# How to get iFrame id from src with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, refresh

**What I want to do:** I've got an HTML page with some iFrames in it.
I need to refresh one particular iFrame after I click on a button.

**My problem:** that iFrame I want to refresh, got a dynamic id, so I can't do this with

```
document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

I would like to obtain that iFrame id from his src, because I know a particular string that is contained in it.

**Question:** is it possible to do something like this? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("iframe[src*=sample]").attr("id");
```

where "sample" is the string which you are looking at.

Once you have the concerned iframe, you don't need the ID. You can simply reload it using the same selector.

More on the attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Good solution, if the ID gets incremented.

Comment: Worked on 1st attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can give name attribute to  element and then take the id of that object.

```
var name = document.getElementsByName("box");
console.log(name[0].id);
```

Fiddle code-http://jsfiddle.net/16xhq5ym/2/